# NSURLSession with backgroundSessionConfiguration timeoutIntervalForRequest does not work

Tags: ios, background, timeout, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

When i create a `NSURLSessionConfiguration` with the `defaultConfiguration`, set the `timeoutIntervalForRequest` at X seconds and use this configuraiton to create a `NSURLSession` and start a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` and X seconds pass without receiving data (didWriteData) after i start (resume) the task, `didCompleteWithError` is called with a timeout error.

BUT if i use the a configuration with **`backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`**
and start a download task as before, the timeout is never triggered (without suspending or closing the app). The only timeout that works is `timeoutIntervalForResource`.

Can a background session work with a timeoutIntervalForRequest?

I have seen some answers where two sessions are created, one for background downloads and one for normal donloads which create&pass resume data when switching from foreground to background and reverse, but i don't know if this is a good idea.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, when you use a background session and the request timeout expires, the download is restarted and doesn't return an error